# Is it a bad idea to access the PersistenceManager inside an InstanceLifecycleEvent (JDO)?

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I would like to audit my entities through JDO using one of the lifecycle listeners.  The spec indicates that any changes I do inside of the listener will be a part of the original transaction.  So, what I am doing is persisting an audit entity for another entity by calling PersistenceManager.makePersistent for the audit entity.  Then, to avoid an endless loop, I ignore any events for the audit entity I just persisted.  Otherwise, Data Nucleus does not prevent me from making a major mistake such as that.

The JDO spec does not say anything about whether accessing the PersistenceManager is permitted from within a lifecycle listener or any other implications if you do (other than the changes will be in the same transaction).

While I am able to implement an audit listener this way, I am wondering if it is a bad idea other than the potential for a stack overflow as noted above.

Comment: I haven't read the specifications, but from what you describe, you seem to rely on implementation details. If JPA states you should not do so that means implicitly that the behaviour can change any time.

Comment: I am comparing JPA with JDO as I work with both JPA and JDO and found it interesting that the JPA spec is more restrictive whereas the JDO spec is much less restrictive and lets you do something like that.  I tested with Datanucleus' implementation of JDO, but was asking a question in regards to best practices and intent.

Comment: suppose the answer to that is "it depends", on what you would be doing with the `PersistenceManager`. If the extra persist isn't going to affect any of the managed objects that causes the event then I wouldn't expect a problem. But then the JDO spec says nothing. Ask the Apache JDO mailing list if you want clarification on such things